# ShareLaTeX Bibliography runs off page (hbox too wide)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, sharelatex

I am using ShareLaTeX and having problems with my bibliography running off the page (hbox too wide).

Whichever style I use I can't seems to find what's causing the problem.

I need a harvard-like citation style (Author, Year) and the Bibliogrpahy to be similar, Author (year). etc. Any ideas?

```
    \documentclass[oneside]{article}

    %graphics
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{ {images/} }
    \usepackage{framed} 
    \usepackage{subfiles}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    %plots
    %\usepackage{pgfplots}
    %\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
    %\usepackage{subcaption}

    %layout and maths packages
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \usepackage[british]{babel}
    \usepackage{csquotes}

    %colored text
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{array}
    \MakeOuterQuote{"}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm,} 
    \usepackage{titlesec}

    %strikethrough text package
    \usepackage{ulem}

    %urls in footnotes
    \usepackage{url}

    %set url font to the same as the rest of the document
    \urlstyle{same}

    %remove footnote indent
    \usepackage[bottom,hang,flushmargin,multiple]{footmisc}

    %appendix
    \usepackage{appendix}
    %Includes "References" in the table of contents
    \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


    \emergencystretch=1em
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage[final]{microtype}


    %Biblatex
    \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=apa,citestyle=apa]{biblatex}

    \DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
    \setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
    \addbibresource{bib.bib}

    \newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
      \begingroup
      \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
      \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
      \endgroup
    }


    \begin{document}


    \tableofcontents{}
    %adds vertical space below the TOC title "Contents"
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\normalbaselineskip}}

    %changes "appendices" to "appendix" in TOC and Appendices page
    \renewcommand\appendixpagename{\Large Appendix}
    \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendix}
    %begin appendix
    \appendix
    \appendixpage
    \addappheadtotoc
\newpage

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

Here's the bibliography:

```
@book{lavoie2009introduction,
  title={Introduction to post-Keynesian economics},
  author={Lavoie, Marc},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{lazonick2014profits,
  title={Profits without prosperity},
  author={Lazonick, William},
  journal={Harvard Business Review},
  volume={92},
  number={9},
  pages={46--55},
  year={2014}
}
@book{lipsey1999principles,
  title={Principles of economics},
  author={Lipsey, Richard G and Chrystal, K Alec},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
@article{Mason2015,
abstract = {The study distinguishes 'regulation' and 'supervision' in the US and provides a concise overview of the structure of US financial supervision. The US legal system limits financial supervision to financial institutions/ products that investors cannot comprehend on the basis of published financial reports, namely banks. But US supervision has historically overlooked the parent institutions of supervised firms. Moreover, the different legal set-up limits direct comparison of US supervisory arrangements with EU objectives. The study, managed by Policy Department A, on request of the Committee on Economic and Monetary Affairs (ECON) aims at facilitating ECON's understanding of the complex US system of financial supervision.},
author = {Mason, Joseph},
journal = {European Parliament's Committee on Economic and Monetary Affairs},
title = {{Overview and Structure of Financial Supervision and Regulation in the US}},
year = {2015}
}
@article{mcleay2014money,
  title={Money in the modern economy: an introduction},
  author={McLeay, Michael and Radia, Amar and Thomas, Ryland},
  year={2014}
}
@book{Mehrling2010,
author = {Mehrling, Perry},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Arlen.Home/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Unknown - Unknown - THE NEW LOMBARD STREET.pdf:pdf},
isbn = {9780691143989},
title = {{The New Lombard Street}},
year = {2010}
}
@techreport{messori2004monetary,
  title={Monetary profits within the circuit: Ponzi finance oer" mors tua, vita mea"?},
  author={Messori, Marcello and Zazzaro, Alberto},
  year={2004},
  institution={Universita'Politecnica delle Marche (I), Dipartimento di Scienze Economiche e Sociali}
}
@book{minsky1976john,
  title={John maynard keynes},
  author={Minsky, Hyman P},
  year={1976},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@misc{Minsky1978,
abstract = {The financial instability hypothesis has both empirical and theoretical aspects. The readily observed empirical aspect is that, from time to time, capitalist economies exhibit inflations and debt deflations which seem to have the potential to spin out of control. In such ... $\backslash$n},
author = {Minsky, Hyman P},
booktitle = {Handbook of Radical Political Economy},
doi = {10.2139/ssrn.161024},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Arlen.Home/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Minsky - 1978 - The Financial Instability Hypothesis A Restatement.pdf:pdf},
isbn = {wp{\_}74},
issn = {1556-5068},
pages = {9},
title = {{The Financial Instability Hypothesis}},
url = {http://digitalcommons.bard.edu/hm{\_}archive/180},
volume = {180},
year = {1992}
}
@book{mirowski2015road,
  title={The Road from Mont P{\`e}lerin},
  author={Mirowski, Philip and Plehwe, Dieter},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Harvard University Press}
}
@article{moore1979endogenous,
  title={The endogenous money stock},
  author={Moore, Basil J},
  journal={Journal of Post Keynesian Economics},
  volume={2},
  number={1},
  pages={49--70},
  year={1979},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
@unpublished{Nikolaidi2017,
abstract = {Minsky cycles have recently gained prominence in the mainstream as well as in the heterodox literature. However, there exists no agreement upon the formal presentation of the Minsky model. The aim of this paper is to survey the literature, clarify the differences, suggest a structure to classify Minsky-inspired models and offer a framework to compare the different approaches. We distinguish between debt cycle models, in which the source of the cyclical dynamics is in the interaction of goods markets and the financial market, and the speculative cycle models in which cycles come from the financial market itself. Within the debt cycle models we make a distinction between the Kalecki-Minsky models that assume a stable goods market equilibrium, the Kaldor-Minsky models which postulate instability in the goods market and the Goodwin-Minsky models that incorporate debt dynamics into the traditional Goodwin interactions between the wage share and employment rate.},
author = {Nikolaidi, Maria and Stockhammer, Engelbert},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Arlen.Home/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Nikolaidi, Stockhammer - 2017 - Minsky models. A structured survey.pdf:pdf},
keywords = {B50,E32,G01,business cycles,debt cycles JEL codes,financial instability,post-Keynesian economics},
pages = {1--51},
title = {{Minsky models . A structured survey}},
year = {2016}
}
@article{palley1994debt,
  title={Debt, aggregate demand, and the business cycle: an analysis in the spirit of Kaldor and Minsky},
  author={Palley, Thomas I},
  journal={Journal of Post Keynesian Economics},
  volume={16},
  number={3},
  pages={371--390},
  year={1994},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
@book{polanyi1957great,
  title={The great transformation},
  author={Polanyi, Karl and MacIver, Robert Morrison},
  volume={5},
  year={1957},
  publisher={Beacon Press Boston}
}
@unpublished{Popoyan2016,
abstract = {After the destructive impact of the global financial crisis of 2008, many believe that pre-crisis financial market regulation did not take the “big picture” of the system sufficiently into ac- count and, subsequently, financial supervision mainly “missed the forest for the trees”. As a result, the need for macroprudential aspects of regulation emerged, which has recently become the focal point of many policy debates. This has also led to intense discussion on the contours of monetary policy after the post-crisis “new normal”. Here, I review recent progress in empirical and theoretical research on the effectiveness of macroprudential tools, as well as the current state of the debate, in order to extract common policy conclusions. The work highlights that, despite the achievements in the literature, the current experience and knowledge of how macroprudential instruments work, their calibration, and the mech- anisms through which they interact with each other and with monetary policy are rather limited and conflicting. Moreover, I critically survey and note the current challenges faced by macroprudential regulation in creating stable, yet efficient financial systems. At the same time, I emphasize the importance of accepting that many risks may remain, requiring that we proceed prudently and develop better plans for future crises.},
author = {Popoyan, Lilit},
booktitle = {LEM Working Paper Series},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Arlen.Home/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Popoyan - 2016 - Macroprudential Policy a Blessing or a Curse.pdf:pdf},
issn = {2284-0400},
keywords = {Basel III regulation,capital adequacy ratio,counter- cyclical capital buffer,crisis management,financial stability.,leverage requirement,macroprudential policy,systemic risk},
title = {{Macroprudential Policy: a Blessing or a Curse?}},
url = {http://www.lem.sssup.it/WPLem/files/2016-21.pdf},
volume = {2016/21},
year = {2016}
}
@incollection{rochon2005existence,
  title={The existence of monetary profits within the monetary circuit},
  author={Rochon, Louis-Philippe},
  booktitle={The Monetary Theory of Production},
  pages={125--138},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@book{romer1996advanced,
  title={Advanced macroeconomic theory},
  author={Romer, David and Chow, Chs},
  year={1996},
  publisher={Mcgraw-hill}
}
@article{romer2016trouble,
  title={The trouble with macroeconomics},
  author={Romer, Paul},
  journal={The American Economist, forthcoming},
  year={2016}
}
@article{ryan2012does,
  title={Where does money come from},
  author={Ryan-Collins, Josh and Greenham, Tony and Werner, Richard and Jackson, Andrew},
  journal={A guide to the UK monetary and banking system},
  volume={2},
  year={2012}
}
@article{ryoo2010long,
  title={Long waves and short cycles in a model of endogenous financial fragility},
  author={Ryoo, Soon},
  journal={Journal of Economic Behavior \& Organization},
  volume={74},
  number={3},
  pages={163--186},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{samuelson1968classical,
  title={What classical and neoclassical monetary theory really was},
  author={Samuelson, Paul A},
  journal={The Canadian Journal of Economics/Revue canadienne d'Economique},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1--15},
  year={1968},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
@article{Schumpeter1928,
abstract = {"Capitalism, while economically stable, and even gaining in stability, creates, by rationalizing the human mind, a mentality and a style of life incompatable with its own fundamental conditions, motives and social institutions, and will be changed, although not by economic necessity and probably even at some sacrifce of economic welfare, into an order of things which it will be merely matter of taste and terminology to call Socialism or not."},
author = {Schumpeter, J},
doi = {10.2307/2224315},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Arlen.Home/Google Drive/Education/Kingston University MA/Dissertation/Readings/Cycles - Minsky/Schumpeter instability of capitalism.pdf:pdf},
isbn = {00130133},
issn = {0013-0133},
journal = {The economic journal},
number = {151},
pages = {361--386},
title = {{The instability of capitalism}},
volume = {38},
year = {1928}
}
@book{say1851treatise,
  title={A treatise on political economy},
  author={Say, Jean Baptiste and Biddle, Clement Cornell},
  year={1851},
  publisher={J. Grigg}
}
@article{Schumpeter1939,
abstract = {Editorial Reviews Peter Lindner, Vice-President, Lehman Brothers Inc. "This book is an invaluable resource for anyone interested in empirical macroeconomics or in advanced techniques of time series analysis. It clearly shows how the adoption of new econometric techniques leads to new and better answers to existing questions, as well as to new questions, too." Salih N. Nefti, Graduate School, City University of New York "This is a comprehensive and scholarly treatment of the business cycle phenomena. It will serve as an excellent guide to researchers as well as practitioners." Book Description This is the most sophisticated and up-to-date econometric analysis of business cycles now available. Francis Diebold and Glenn Rudebusch have long been acknowledged as leading experts on business cycles. And here they present a highly integrative collection of their most important essays on the subject, along with a detailed introduction that draws together the book's principal themes and findings. Diebold and Rudebusch use the latest quantitative methods to address five principal questions Diebold and Rudebusch use the latest quantitative methods to address five principal questions about the measurement, modeling, and forecasting of business cycles. They ask whether business cycles have become more moderate in the postwar period, concluding that recessions have, in fact, been shorter and shallower. They consider whether economic expansions and contractions tend to die of "old age." Contrary to popular wisdom, they find little evidence that expansions become more fragile the longer they last, although they do find that contractions are increasingly likely to end as they age. The authors discuss the defining characteristics of business cycles, focusing on how economic variables move together and on the timing of the slow alternation between expansions and contractions. They explore the difficulties of distinguishing between long-term trends in the economy and cyclical fluctuations. And they examine how business cycles can be forecast, looking in particular at how to predict turning points in cycles, rather than merely the level of future economic activity. They show here that the index of leading economic indicators is a poor predictor of future economic activity, and consider what we can learn from other indicators, such as financial variables. Throughout, the authors make use of a variety of advanced econometric techniques, including nonparametric analysis, fractional integration, and regime-switching models. Business Cycles is crucial reading for policymakers, bankers, and business executives About the Author Francis X. Diebold is Professor of Economics and of Statistics at the University of Pennsylvania and Faculty Research Fellow at the National Bureau of Economic Research. He is the author of Elements of Forecasting and Empirical Models of Exchange Rate Dynamics. Glenn D. Rudebusch is a research officer at the Federal Reserve Bank of San Francisco. He is the author of The Estimation of Macroeconomic Disequilibrium Models with Regime Classification Information.},
author = {Schumpeter, J},
doi = {10.1086/255640},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Arlen.Home/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Marschak - 1940 - iBusiness Cycles A Theoretical, Historical, and Statistical Analysis of the Capitalist Processi . Joseph A. Schumpeter.pdf:pdf},
isbn = {1578985560, 9781578985562},
issn = {0022-3808},
pmid = {17196315},
title = {{Business Cycles: A Theoretical, Historical, and Statistical Analysis of the Capitalist Process . Joseph A. Schumpeter}},
url = {http://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.1086/255640},
year = {1939}
}
@article{adrian2010liquidity,
  title={Liquidity and leverage},
  author={Adrian, Tobias and Shin, Hyun Song},
  journal={Journal of financial intermediation},
  volume={19},
  number={3},
  pages={418--437},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{skott2008growth,
  title={Growth, instability and cycles: Harrodian and Kaleckian models of accumulation and income distribution},
  author={Skott, Peter},
  year={2008}
}
@book{steil2013battle,
  title={The battle of Bretton Woods},
  author={Steil, Benn},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Princeton University Press}
}
@article{stockhammer2015debt,
  title={Debt-driven growth? Wealth, distribution and demand in OECD countries},
  author={Stockhammer, Engelbert and Wildauer, Rafael},
  journal={Cambridge Journal of Economics},
  volume={40},
  number={6},
  pages={1609--1634},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
@article{SudiptoBhattacharyaCAEGoodhartDimitriosTsomocosAlexandrosVardoulakis2011,
abstract = {Sudipto Bhattacharya has been Professor of Finance at LSE since 1995, prior to which he has taught at the Universities of Chicago, Stanford, Berkeley, Michigan, and Delhi. His main areas of research interest are corporate financial policy under asymmetric information, theories and regulation of banking activities cum crises, sharing of intellectual property under alternative institutional structures, and applied game theory. He has published around forty academic papers on these themes. Quantitative Methods from the Athens University of Economics and Business. His main areas of research interest are asset pricing under incomplete markets and default, financial stability, and market microstructure. He is currently doing research on the effects of the Basel III reforms on financial stability and the real economy. Prior to his DPhil studies he worked in the financial sector as an equity analyst. Any opinions expressed here are those of the authors and not necessarily those of the FMG. The research findings reported in this paper are the result of the independent research of the authors and do not necessarily reflect the views of the LSE. Abstract Busts after periods of prolonged prosperity have been found to be catastrophic. Financial in-stitutions increase their leverage and shift their portfolios towards projects that were previously considered too risky. This results from institutions rationally updating their expectations and becoming more optimistic about the future prospects of the economy. Default is inevitably harsher when a bad shock occurs after periods of good news. Commonly used measures to forecast risk in the system, such as VIX, fail to capture this phenomenon, as they are also bi-ased by optimistic expectations. Competition among financial institutions for better relative performance exacerbates the boom-bust cycle. We explore the relative advantages of alterna-tive regulations in reducing financial fragility, and suggest a novel criterion for improvement of aggregate welfare.},
author = {{Sudipto Bhattacharya, CAE Goodhart, Dimitrios Tsomocos}, Alexandros Vardoulakis},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Arlen.Home/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Sudipto Bhattacharya CAE Goodhart Dimitrios Tsomocos Alexandros Vardoulakis et al. - 2011 - Minsky's Financial Instability Hypothesis an.pdf:pdf},
keywords = {D81,D83,E44,Financial Instability,G01,G21,Leverage,Minsky,Optimism,Procyclicality,Relative Perfor-mance JEL Classification},
title = {{Minsky's Financial Instability Hypothesis and the Leverage Cycle LSE}},
year = {2011}
}
@article{taylor1985minsky,
  title={A Minsky crisis},
  author={Taylor, Lance and O'Connell, Stephen A},
  journal={The Quarterly Journal of Economics},
  volume={100},
  number={Supplement},
  pages={871--885},
  year={1985},
  publisher={MIT Press}
}
@article{thurm2013companies,
  title={As companies step up buybacks, executives benefit, too},
  author={Thurm, Scott and Ng, Serena},
  journal={Wall Street Journal},
  year={2013}
}
@article{tomasson2010source,
  title={What is the Source of Profit and Interest? A Classical Conundrum Reconsidered},
  author={Tomasson, Gunnar and Bezemer, Dirk J},
  year={2010}
}
@article{Toporowski2012,
author = {Toporowski, Jan},
journal = {SOAS Department of Economics Working Paper Series},
title = {{Corporate Liquidity and Financial Fragility: The Role of Investment, Debt and Interest}},
volume = {No. 169},
year = {2012}
}
@article{Tymoigne2010,
author = {Tymoigne, Eric},
journal = {Levy Working Paper},
number = {637},
pages = {1--33},
title = {{Financial Stability, Regulatory Buffers, and Economic Growth: Some Postrecession Regulatory Implications}},
year = {2010}
}
@book{varian1978microeconomic,
  title={Microeconomic analysis},
  author={Varian, Hal R},
  number={338.5 V299m 1978},
  year={1978},
  publisher={WW Norton}
}
@article{werner2012towards,
  title={Towards a new research programme on ‘banking and the economy’—Implications of the Quantity Theory of Credit for the prevention and resolution of banking and debt crises},
  author={Werner, Richard A},
  journal={International Review of Financial Analysis},
  volume={25},
  pages={1--17},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{werner2014can,
  title={Can banks individually create money out of nothing?—The theories and the empirical evidence},
  author={Werner, Richard A},
  journal={International Review of Financial Analysis},
  volume={36},
  pages={1--19},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{witztum2005economics,
  title={Economics: an analytical introduction},
  author={Witztum, Amos and others},
  journal={OUP Catalogue},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
@book{wray2015modern,
  title={Modern money theory: A primer on macroeconomics for sovereign monetary systems},
  author={Wray, L Randall},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{Yamaguchi2016,
author = {Yamaguchi, Kaoru},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Arlen.Home/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Yamaguchi - 2016 - Money and Macroeconomic Dynamics.pdf:pdf},
isbn = {9784907291013},
pages = {1--520},
title = {{Money and Macroeconomic Dynamics}},
year = {2015}
}
@article{Zezza2011,
abstract = {In this paper we discuss some issues in the Monetary Theory of Production {\`{a}} la Graziani, such as the " paradox of profits " , in the light of the stock-flow-consistent approach pioneered by Wynne Godley, to resolve some apparent inconsistencies and show the common features of the two post-Keynesian approaches.},
author = {Zezza, Gennaro},
doi = {10.1057/9780230367357_8},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Arlen.Home/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Zezza - 2011 - Godley and Graziani Stock-Flow-Consistent Monetary Circuits.pdf:pdf},
journal = {Contributions in Stock-Flow Modeling: Essays in Honor {\ldots}},
keywords = {B50 Introduction and motivation,E12,E44,E52,Godley,Graziani Jel-codes,circuit theory,monetary theory of production,stock-flow-consistency},
title = {{Godley and Graziani: Stock-Flow-Consistent Monetary Circuits}},
year = {2012}
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: About half of the 41 [!!] bibliographic entries you've posted contain errors: some are annoying spelling errors, others are about using incorrect and inapplicable entry types. Please, please take the time to correct these factual errors. The readers of your document(s) will thank you.

Comment: Many thanks! I had downloaded sources from various places online and added these files to Mendeley--but Mendeley often can't find the data associated with the pdf file I load--so it finds something close and just uses that. I've had to start going through title by title and pull the data from google scholar, bibtex entry, but even then with new papers or peripherally published papers, such as working papers or speeches, the system doesn't work very well. It seems like econ doesn't source material as well as the scieneces?

Comment: The two most serious types of errors in the list you provided are (a) use of an incorrect entry type -- e.g., inappropriate use of `@article` when `@book`, `@misc`, or `@techreport` should be used -- and (b) inappropriate lowercasing -- e.g., "`title={John maynard keynes}`" and `journal = {The economic journal},`, to name but two of many offenders. Keep in mind: *You* are responsible for the correctness of your document, including its bibliography. Blaming Mendeley and Google Scholar for the errors in your bibliography isn't going to cut it with your readers. If a tool is poor, don't use it.

Comment: Fair enough--but if no one complains, there will be no progress. "Better tools I say!" =)

Comment: @Arlen at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/36296 you can find a few common problems of automatically generated bib entries.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is caused by the `ulem` package, which causes the titles of your bib item to be underlined and the underlined text cannot break lines, thus producing into the margin. If you remove the `ulem` package, line breaks work as expected. or if you need the `ulem` package, call it with `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` to prevent it from modifying the behaviour of `\emph{}`.

Then a few other problems in your code:

- the `apa` style needs `biber` to compile, so you have to change the backend from `bibtex` to `biber` or delete it altogether, as `biber` is the default.
- You should have a look at your `messori2004monetary` bibentry, the way you use `"` there causes problems with `csquotes`.
- the entry `SudiptoBhattacharyaCAEGoodhartDimitriosTsomocosAlexandrosVardoulakis2011` has a syntax problem in the author field
- the title of `werner2012towards` has non standard characters, which cause problems. Same for `werner2014can`.
- you might want to check the content of your bib entries, `isbn = {wp{\_}74},` does not seem to be a valid isbn number
- and what [Mico said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385924/sharelatex-bibliography-runs-off-page-hbox-to-wide/385930#comment956126_385924) :)

## Summary:

Don't ignore error messages in the .log file

---

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{Mason2015,
    author = {Mason, Joseph},
    journal = {European Parliament's Committee on Economic and Monetary Affairs},
    title = {{Overview and Structure of Financial Supervision and Regulation in the US}},
    year = {2015}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had upvoted your answer even before you provided a link to my comment. :-)