# Overfull \hbox (x pt too wide) in biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex for the bibliography. I'm facing three "too wide" lines.

This is the main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{packages}


\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the `packages.tex` file

```
% Last update date 01/01/2022


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Essential
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Accept different input encodings
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Multilingual support for LaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and Plain TeX
%\decimalpoint % decimal separator to .

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/option-clash-for-package-xcolor


\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{lib.bib} %Import the bibliography file
\nocite{*} % Write in the bibliography all references, not only cited

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% LaTeX improvements

% Basic maths
\usepackage{amsmath} % AMS mathematical facilities for LaTeX
\usepackage{amsfonts} % TeX fonts from the American Mathematical Society
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Fonts to typeset mathematics to match Palatino

% General
\usepackage{caption} % Customising captions in floating environments
\usepackage{subcaption} % Support for sub-captions
\usepackage{paracol} % Multiple columns with texts “in parallel”
\usepackage{multicol} % Intermix single and multiple columns
\usepackage{graphicx} % Enhanced support for graphics
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Produces figures which text can flow around
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % Extensive support for hypertext in LaTeX
\usepackage{vmargin} % Set various page dimensions
\usepackage{verbatim} % Reimplementation of and extensions to LaTeX verbatim
\usepackage{xargs} % Define commands with many optional arguments
\usepackage{enumitem} % Control layout of itemize, enumerate, description
%\begin{itemize}[label={\alpha}]
\usepackage{lipsum} % Easy access to the Lorem Ipsum and other dummy texts
\usepackage{array} % Extending the array and tabular environments
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % Package for underlining, see also
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385924/sharelatex-bibliography-runs-off-page-hbox-too-wide
\usepackage{cleveref} % Intelligent cross-referencing
\usepackage{enumitem} % Controll of itemize, enumerate and description environments

% Tables
\usepackage{booktabs} % Publication quality tables in LaTeX
\usepackage{colortbl} % Add colour to LaTeX tables
\usepackage{diagbox} % Table heads with diagonal lines
\usepackage{multicol} % Intermix single and multiple columns
\usepackage{multirow} % Create tabular cells spanning multiple rows

% Other programming language
\usepackage{listings} % Typeset source code listings using LaTeX
\usepackage{pythontex} % Run Python from within a document, typesetting the results

% Colors
\usepackage{xcolor} % Driver-independent color extensions for LaTeX and pdfLaTeX

% Boxes
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} % Framed environments that can split at page boundaries


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Maths

% More maths
\usepackage{stackrel} % Allows supercript above and bellow a symbol
%A \stackbin[\text{and}]{}{+} B \stackrel[x]{!}{=} C
\usepackage{cancel} %Place lines through maths formulae


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Fonts
\usepackage{fontawesome} % Font containing web-related icons
\usepackage{helvet} % Load Helvetica, scaled
\usepackage{eurosym} % METAFONT and macros for Euro sign
% \euro


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Physics
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx} % A comprehensive (SI) units package


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Chemistry
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
```

And this is the `lib.bib` file:

```
@Article{Collaboration2020,
  author        = {CMS Collaboration},
  journal       = {JHEP 03 (2021) 095},
  title         = {Search for new physics in top quark production with additional leptons in proton-proton collisions at $\sqrt{s} =$ 13 TeV using effective field theory},
  year          = {2020},
  month         = dec,
  abstract      = {Events containing one or more top quarks produced with additional prompt leptons are used to search for new physics within the framework of an effective field theory (EFT). The data correspond to an integrated luminosity of 41.5 fb$^{-1}$ of proton-proton collisions at a center-of-mass energy of 13 TeV at the LHC, collected by the CMS experiment in 2017. The selected events are required to have either two leptons with the same charge or more than two leptons; jets, including identified bottom quark jets, are also required, and the selected events are divided into categories based on the multiplicities of these objects. Sixteen dimension-six operators that can affect processes involving top quarks produced with additional charged leptons are considered in this analysis. Constructed to target EFT effects directly, the analysis applies a novel approach in which the observed yields are parameterized in terms of the Wilson coefficients (WCs) of the EFT operators. A simultaneous fit of the 16 WCs to the data is performed and two standard deviation confidence intervals for the WCs are extracted; the standard model expectations for the WC values are within these intervals for all of the WCs probed.},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  doi           = {10.1007/JHEP03(2021)095},
  eprint        = {2012.04120},
  file          = {:http\://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.04120v3:PDF},
  keywords      = {hep-ex},
  primaryclass  = {hep-ex},
}

@MastersThesis{Reissel2016,
  author = {Christina Rei{\ss}el},
  school = {Georg-August-Universität Göttingen},
  title  = {Monte Carlo simulation and analysis of the {$t\bar{t}H$} process with the ATLAS experiment at {$\sqrt{s}=13$} TeV},
  year   = {2016},
  type   = {BA thesis},
}

@MastersThesis{Dreyer2014,
  author = {Timo Dreyer},
  school = {Georg-August-Universität Göttingen},
  title  = {{$t\bar{t}H$} Production at LHC},
  year   = {2014},
  type   = {BA thesis},
}

@MastersThesis{Wiebe2014,
  author = {Felix Wiebe},
  school = {Georg-August-Universität Göttingen},
  title  = {Analysis of {$pp\rightarrow t\bar{t}H$} Events},
  year   = {2014},
  type   = {BA thesis},
}

@MastersThesis{Casines2021,
  author = {Luis Marcos López Casines},
  school = {Universitat de Valencia},
  title  = {Probing the top quark Yukawa coupling and possible new physics effects in the {$t\bar{t}H$} and {$tH$} processes},
  year   = {2021},
}

@Article{Alwall2011,
  author        = {Johan Alwall and Michel Herquet and Fabio Maltoni and Olivier Mattelaer and Tim Stelzer},
  title         = {MadGraph 5 : Going Beyond},
  year          = {2011},
  month         = jun,
  abstract      = {MadGraph 5 is the new version of the MadGraph matrix element generator, written in the Python programming language. It implements a number of new, efficient algorithms that provide improved performance and functionality in all aspects of the program. It features a new user interface, several new output formats including C++ process libraries for Pythia 8, and full compatibility with FeynRules for new physics models implementation, allowing for event generation for any model that can be written in the form of a Lagrangian. MadGraph 5 builds on the same philosophy as the previous versions, and its design allows it to be used as a collaborative platform where theoretical, phenomenological and simulation projects can be developed and then distributed to the high-energy community. We describe the ideas and the most important developments of the code and illustrate its capabilities through a few simple phenomenological examples.},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  doi           = {10.1007/JHEP06(2011)128},
  eprint        = {1106.0522},
  file          = {:Alwall2011 - MadGraph 5 _ Going beyond.pdf:PDF},
  keywords      = {hep-ph},
  primaryclass  = {hep-ph},
}

@Article{Alwall2014,
  author        = {J. Alwall and R. Frederix and S. Frixione and V. Hirschi and F. Maltoni and O. Mattelaer and H. -S. Shao and T. Stelzer and P. Torrielli and M. Zaro},
  journal       = {JHEP07(2014)079},
  title         = {The automated computation of tree-level and next-to-leading order differential cross sections, and their matching to parton shower simulations},
  year          = {2014},
  month         = may,
  abstract      = {We discuss the theoretical bases that underpin the automation of the computations of tree-level and next-to-leading order cross sections, of their matching to parton shower simulations, and of the merging of matched samples that differ by light-parton multiplicities. We present a computer program, MadGraph5_aMC@NLO, capable of handling all these computations -- parton-level fixed order, shower-matched, merged -- in a unified framework whose defining features are flexibility, high level of parallelisation, and human intervention limited to input physics quantities. We demonstrate the potential of the program by presenting selected phenomenological applications relevant to the LHC and to a 1-TeV $e^+e^-$ collider. While next-to-leading order results are restricted to QCD corrections to SM processes in the first public version, we show that from the user viewpoint no changes have to be expected in the case of corrections due to any given renormalisable Lagrangian, and that the implementation of these are well under way.},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  doi           = {10.1007/JHEP07(2014)079},
  eprint        = {1405.0301},
  file          = {:Alwall2014 - The Automated Computation of Tree Level and Next to Leading Order Differential Cross Sections, and Their Matching to Parton Shower Simulations.pdf:PDF},
  keywords      = {hep-ph},
  primaryclass  = {hep-ph},
}

@Article{Brun1997,
  author  = {Brun, R. and Rademakers, F.},
  journal = {Nucl. Instrum. Meth. A},
  title   = {{ROOT: An object oriented data analysis framework}},
  year    = {1997},
  pages   = {81--86},
  volume  = {389},
  doi     = {10.1016/S0168-9002(97)00048-X},
  editor  = {Werlen, M. and Perret-Gallix, D.},
}

@Misc{Python,
  howpublished = {\url{https://www.python.org/}},
  note         = {Accessed: 2022-04-20},
  title        = {{\texttt{Python}} documentation},
}

@Misc{PyROOT,
  howpublished = {\url{https://root.cern/manual/python/}},
  note         = {Accessed: 2022-04-20},
  title        = {{\texttt{PyROOT}} documentation},
}

@Misc{TRExFitter,
  howpublished = {\url{https://trexfitter-docs.web.cern.ch/trexfitter-docs/}},
  note         = {Accessed: 2022-04-20},
  title        = {{\texttt{TRExFitter}} documentation},
}

@Misc{Cplusplus,
  howpublished = {\url{https://isocpp.org/}},
  note         = {Accessed: 2022-04-20},
  title        = {{\texttt{C++}} documentation},
}

@Article{LesHouchesFiles,
  author        = {J. Alwall and A. Ballestrero and P. Bartalini and S. Belov and E. Boos and A. Buckley and J. M. Butterworth and L. Dudko and S. Frixione and L. Garren and S. Gieseke and A. Gusev and I. Hinchliffe and J. Huston and B. Kersevan and F. Krauss and N. Lavesson and L. Lönnblad and E. Maina and F. Maltoni and M. L. Mangano and F. Moortgat and S. Mrenna and C. G. Papadopoulos and R. Pittau and P. Richardson and M. H. Seymour and A. Sherstnev and T. Sjöstrand and P. Skands and S. R. Slabospitsky and Z. Wcas and B. R. Webber and M. Worek and D. Zeppenfeld},
  journal       = {Comput.Phys.Commun.176:300-304,2007},
  title         = {A standard format for Les Houches Event Files},
  year          = {2006},
  month         = sep,
  abstract      = {A standard file format is proposed to store process and event information, primarily output from parton-level event generators for further use by general-purpose ones. The information content is identical with what was already defined by the Les Houches Accord five years ago, but then in terms of Fortran commonblocks. This information is embedded in a minimal XML-style structure, for clarity and to simplify parsing.},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  doi           = {10.1016/j.cpc.2006.11.010},
  eprint        = {hep-ph/0609017},
  file          = {:Alwall2006 - A Standard Format for Les Houches Event Files.pdf:PDF},
  keywords      = {hep-ph},
  primaryclass  = {hep-ph},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

I'm runing the code at Overleaf and there are three warnings:

```
Overfull \hbox (26.1061pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--8
Overfull \hbox (12.87477pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--8
Overfull \hbox (5.9195pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--8
```

[image: This is the document.]

I found some solutions about too wide lines with url in the bibliography, but that does not apply here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Some of fields in several bibliographic entries appear to be in a bad mess. E.g., what's with the strangely composite field `journal = {Comput.Phys.Commun.176:300-304,2007}`? Why aren't you using four [4!] separate fields, say, `journal = {Comput. Phys. Commun.},`, `volume = {176},` `pages = {300--304},` and `year = {2007}`?

Comment: @Mico , I imported that reference using the JabRef web browser, so I assumed it was correct, now I see that it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a number of possible causes for overfull and undefull boxes in the bibliography. Generally speaking the problem is with content for which LaTeX has a hard time finding good ways to line-break or hyphenate.

It is next to impossible to give a comprehensive list of all possible issues you might face, but the most common problems are listed in [How to adjust the breaking in the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864). The answer there also discusses 'general' solutions.

In your case you can already get much better results if you improve the input data. First of all, you may be able to get better results if you tell JabRef to export `biblatex` data instead of classical BibTeX data.

One obvious problem with your entries is

```
@Article{LesHouchesFiles,
  author        = {J. Alwall and A. Ballestrero and P. Bartalini and S. Belov and E. Boos and A. Buckley and J. M. Butterworth and L. Dudko and S. Frixione and L. Garren and S. Gieseke and A. Gusev and I. Hinchliffe and J. Huston and B. Kersevan and F. Krauss and N. Lavesson and L. Lönnblad and E. Maina and F. Maltoni and M. L. Mangano and F. Moortgat and S. Mrenna and C. G. Papadopoulos and R. Pittau and P. Richardson and M. H. Seymour and A. Sherstnev and T. Sjöstrand and P. Skands and S. R. Slabospitsky and Z. Wcas and B. R. Webber and M. Worek and D. Zeppenfeld},
  journal       = {Comput.Phys.Commun.176:300-304,2007},
  title         = {A standard format for Les Houches Event Files},
  year          = {2006},
  month         = sep,
  abstract      = {A standard file format is proposed to store process and event information, primarily output from parton-level event generators for further use by general-purpose ones. The information content is identical with what was already defined by the Les Houches Accord five years ago, but then in terms of Fortran commonblocks. This information is embedded in a minimal XML-style structure, for clarity and to simplify parsing.},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  doi           = {10.1016/j.cpc.2006.11.010},
  eprint        = {hep-ph/0609017},
  file          = {:Alwall2006 - A Standard Format for Les Houches Event Files.pdf:PDF},
  keywords      = {hep-ph},
  primaryclass  = {hep-ph},
}
```

where far too much (unbreakable!) stuff ended up in the `journal` field. The `journal` field should only contain the journal name. Volume, pages and year should go into the respective dedicated fields.

Another possible issue is

```
school = {Georg-August-Universität Göttingen},
```

for several reasons: Firstly, in an English document LaTeX might have a hard time finding correct hyphenation points for the German name. Secondly, words containing hyphens can only be broken at the hyphen, leaving large parts unbreakable (you can use the command `\hyphen` to insert a hyphen that does not stop other hyphenation).

The following cleaned-up file produces no box warnings for me.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Collaboration2020,
  author        = {CMS Collaboration},
  journal       = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
  title         = {Search for New Physics in Top Quark Production
                   With Additional Leptons in Proton-Proton Collisions
                   at {$\sqrt{s} = 13$~TeV} Using Effective Field Theory},
  volume        = {2021},
  year          = {2021},
  eid           = {95},
  doi           = {10.1007/JHEP03(2021)095},
  eprinttype    = {arxiv},
  eprint        = {2012.04120},
  eprintclass   = {hep-ex},
}
@thesis{Reissel2016,
  author = {Christina Reißel},
  school = {Georg\hyphen August\hyphen Universität Göttingen},
  title  = {{Monte Carlo} Simulation and Analysis
            of the {$t\bar{t}H$} Process With the {ATLAS} experiment
            at {$\sqrt{s}=13$~TeV}},
  year   = {2016},
  type   = {BA thesis},
}
@thesis{Dreyer2014,
  author = {Timo Dreyer},
  school = {Georg\hyphen August\hyphen Universität Göttingen},
  title  = {{$t\bar{t}H$} Production at {LHC}},
  year   = {2014},
  type   = {BA thesis},
}
@thesis{Wiebe2014,
  author = {Felix Wiebe},
  school = {Georg\hyphen August\hyphen Universität Göttingen},
  title  = {Analysis of {$pp\rightarrow t\bar{t}H$} Events},
  year   = {2014},
  type   = {BA thesis},
}
@thesis{Casines2021,
  author = {Luis Marcos López Casines},
  school = {Universitat de Valencia},
  title  = {Probing the Top Quark {Yukawa} Coupling
            and Possible New Physics Effects
            in the {$t\bar{t}H$} and {$tH$} Processes},
  year   = {2021},
}
@article{Alwall2011,
  author        = {Johan Alwall and Michel Herquet and Fabio Maltoni
                   and Olivier Mattelaer and Tim Stelzer},
  title         = {MadGraph 5: Going Beyond},
  journal       = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
  year          = {2011},
  volume        = {2011},
  eid           = {128},
  month         = jun,
  doi           = {10.1007/JHEP06(2011)128},
  eprinttype    = {arxiv},
  eprint        = {1106.0522},
  eprintclass   = {hep-ph},
}
@article{Alwall2014,
  author        = {J. Alwall and R. Frederix and S. Frixione and V. Hirschi
                   and F. Maltoni and O. Mattelaer and H.-S. Shao
                   and T. Stelzer and P. Torrielli and M. Zaro},
  journal       = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
  title         = {The Automated Computation of Tree-level
                   and Next-to-leading Order Differential Cross Sections,
                   and Their Matching to Parton Shower Simulations},
  year          = {2014},
  month         = may,
  doi           = {10.1007/JHEP07(2014)079},
  eprinttype    = {arxiv},
  eprint        = {1405.0301},
  eprintclass   = {hep-ph},
}
@article{Brun1997,
  author  = {Brun, R. and Rademakers, F.},
  journal = {Nucl. Instrum. Meth. A},
  title   = {{ROOT}: An Object Oriented Data Analysis Framework},
  year    = {1997},
  pages   = {81-86},
  volume  = {389},
  doi     = {10.1016/S0168-9002(97)00048-X},
}
@online{Python,
  url     = {https://www.python.org/},
  urldate = {2022-04-20},
  title   = {{\texttt{Python}} documentation},
}
@online{PyROOT,
  url     = {https://root.cern/manual/python/},
  urldate = {2022-04-20},
  title   = {{\texttt{PyROOT}} documentation},
}
@online{TRExFitter,
  url     = {https://trexfitter-docs.web.cern.ch/trexfitter-docs/},
  urldate = {2022-04-20},
  title   = {{\texttt{TRExFitter}} documentation},
}
@online{Cplusplus,
  url     = {https://isocpp.org/},
  urldate = {2022-04-20},
  title   = {{\texttt{C++}} documentation},
}

@Article{LesHouchesFiles,
  author        = {J. Alwall and A. Ballestrero and P. Bartalini
                   and S. Belov and E. Boos and A. Buckley
                   and J. M. Butterworth and L. Dudko and S. Frixione
                   and L. Garren and S. Gieseke and A. Gusev and I. Hinchliffe
                   and J. Huston and B. Kersevan and F. Krauss and N. Lavesson
                   and L. Lönnblad and E. Maina and F. Maltoni and M. L. Mangano
                   and F. Moortgat and S. Mrenna and C. G. Papadopoulos
                   and R. Pittau and P. Richardson and M. H. Seymour
                   and A. Sherstnev and T. Sjöstrand and P. Skands
                   and S. R. Slabospitsky and Z. Wcas and B. R. Webber
                   and M. Worek and D. Zeppenfeld},
  journal       = {Computer Physics Communications},
  title         = {A Standard Format for {Les Houches Event Files}},
  year          = {2006},
  month         = sep,
  volume        = {176},
  pages         = {300-304},
  doi           = {10.1016/j.cpc.2006.11.010},
  eprinttype    = {arxiv},
  eprint        = {hep-ph/0609017},
  eprintclass   = {hep-ph},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: bibliography without box warnings]

It is entirely possible that even with good data you still get bad boxes. You will then have to find out the cause of each of those warnings and find a solution or use one of the global solutions discussed in [How to adjust the breaking in the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864).